# ASP.NET VS2008 Calling a function from master page inside template

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

So I have a master page which has the following function

```
 '# Get and/or Set the Page ID
Public Property GetPageId() As String
    Get
        Return pgId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        pgId = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In my template then i.e Default.aspx who references the master page as follows

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/LoggedIn.Master" CodeBehind="Content.aspx.vb" Inherits="udpharmalecheile.WebForm2" %>
```

How can I call this masterpage function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want is the `MasterType` attribute.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my test, my MasterPage is a class named Site1, replace it by your current name and it should work:

```
  Dim myMaster As Site1 = Master
    Response.Write(myMaster.GetPageId)
```

Clayton